# delphi, Fill TdxMemData image column with some images in Ressource and display it in cxGrid

Tags: image, delphi, devexpress

i have dxMemData with image Filed, and some png images located in ressource, i expose this images by singleton object like that:

```
  type
  ImagesRessource = class
  private
    constructor Create;
  public
    Man24: TPngImage;
    Woman24: TPngImage;
    RSMan24: TResourceStream;
    RSWoman24: TResourceStream;

    procedure Load_Man24;
    procedure Load_Woman24;
  end;

var
  Images: ImagesRessource;

implementation

constructor ImagesRessource.Create;
begin
  Load_Man24;
  Load_Woman24;
end;

procedure ImagesRessource.Load_Man24;    
begin 
     Man24 := TPngImage.Create;
     RSMan24 := TResourceStream.Create(hInstance, 'men_24', RT_RCDATA);
     Man24.LoadFromStream(RSMan24); 
end;

procedure ImagesRessource.Load_Woman24;    
begin
  Woman24 := TPngImage.Create;     
  RSWoman24 := TResourceStream.Create(hInstance, 'woman_24', RT_RCDATA);
  Woman24.LoadFromStream(RSWoman24);
end;

initialization 

Images := ImagesRessource.Create;

end.
```

after that, filling the dxMemeData like that

```
if(dxMemData1.FieldByName('isMale').AsBoolean) then        TBlobField(dxMemData1.FieldByName('SexeImg')).LoadFromStream(OverB.Besalama.Properties.V7.Images.RSMan24)
else        TBlobField(dxMemData1.FieldByName('SexeImg')).LoadFromStream(OverB.Besalama.Properties.V7.Images.RSWoman24);
```

the problem now with cxGrid, the image column dosnt't show any thing! i don't know why? or how to create cxgrid image ?

Answer (score 0):

To display Image on CxGrid columns, set the column propertys to **ImageComboBox** and set **Images** to a imagelist.